# How to resize HTML background video?

Tags: html, css

From a website theme, I have the following which cuts off the top of my video. I want to be able to re-size the video, even if it means not stretching across the full screen -

```
<section class="home-section bg-dark-30" id="home" data-background="assets/images/section-5.jpg">
        <div class="video-player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY_VIDEO_URL', containment:'.home-section', startAt:2, mute:true, autoPlay:true, loop:true, opacity:1, showControls:false, showYTLogo:false, vol:0}"></div>
        <div class="video-controls-box">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="video-controls"><a class="fa fa-volume-up" id="video-volume" href="#">&nbsp;</a><a class="fa fa-pause" id="video-play" href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="titan-caption">
          <div class="caption-content">
            <div class="font-alt mb-30 titan-title-size-1">Hello &amp; welcome</div>
            <div class="font-alt mb-40 titan-title-size-4">asdf</div><a class="section-scroll btn btn-border-w btn-round" href="#about">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Here is the CSS of `home-section`:

```
.home-section {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

How can I do this?

Link to template html page that I'm modifying:

http://markup.themewagon.com/titan/index_mp_classic_video_background.html

The area on my browser measures to be 1900 x 800 pixels. My video is 1280 x 720. So the proportions don't work out properly, and video gets cut off. Thus I Want to resize.

Hope that makes sense, thankful for any help. Any questions or anything not clear let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing to `background-size: contain;`, so it scales the video so it fills the screen size

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried but doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Are you overriding the theme's css or writing your own? If I try the change on the link you provided it actually makes the background fit the screen instead of filling it

Comment: I'm editing the theme's "styles.css" file under assets, which is from where I pasted the `home-section` css. How should I do this, like what code in what file? Sorry I'm a beginner at web stuff.

Comment: I see, actually that would be the right approach, I don't know why it shouldn't work... maybe I'm not understanding the behavior you expect; I'll add a picture of what I mean on the answer just to clarify

Comment: by the way, after you change the property, try reloading the browser with Ctrl + F5

Comment: Yeah I've tried re-loading, same code, no results. Really frustrating. The other related part of my question: is there a way to add a margin from the top nav bar? So that the video doesn't overlap over the nav bar.

Comment: You can do that, the `margin-top:` would actually go on the same class as the section, since that's what you have to push down